# How to represent an alias for a module in a .d.ts file?

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript file which for the sake of simplicity also has an alias, something like:

```
module MyLongModuleName{
    // Lots of exported methods and objects... //
}
import m = MyLongModuleName;
```

And this all works as expected if I have the actual typescript file in the same project, however the alias is missing from the .d.ts file so I get errors when I try to use it.

How can I define this sort of alias within the .d.ts file, or alternatively how can I alias the module in such a way as it will be included correctly in to .d.ts file when the ts file is compiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example `.d.ts` of your module:

```
declare module MyLongModuleName {
    export class X {

    }
}

declare var m: typeof MyLongModuleName;
```

You can then use the alias in your code:

```
/// <reference path="example.d.ts" />

var x = new m.X();
```